# New column with rowtotals

Tags: sql

I'm having some trouble to achieve the folowing result.

This is my current table:

```
ID       NR        COST
1       7001       100
2       7001       50
3       7020       800
4       7020       190
5       7050       205
6       7050       80
```

And this is the table I want to achieve:

```
ID       NR        COST   TOTAL
1       7001       100     150
2       7001       50      150
3       7020       800     990
4       7020       190     990
5       7050       205     285
6       7050       80      285
```

So I want to create an extra column, where the sum of the same 'NR' column is.

I have tried working with SUM, but then the whole sum of the cost column is taken.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT distinct id, nr, cost, sum(cost) as total
FROM customers
group by id, nr, cost
```

Comment: I have updated my post with my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to calculate the total for each NR and then just add it to the original result:

```
SELECT id, 
       nr, 
       cost, 
       A.subtotal AS TOTAL 
FROM   table1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT nr, 
                          Sum(cost) AS subTotal 
                   FROM   table1 
                   GROUP  BY nr) AS A 
               ON table1.nr = A.nr
```

Comment: Thx for this solution. However, as A didn't work, I needed to remove the 'as', then all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can self join with an aggregate query:

```
SELECT   id, mytalbe.nr, cost, total
FORM     mytable
JOIN ON  (SELECT    nr, SUM(cost) AS total
          FROM      mytable
          GROUP BY  nr) t ON t.nr = mytable.nr
```